# CSRF fails when form submitted inside an Iframe

Tags: http, csrf

I have a basic HTML form with a token located on domain-a.com.

[www.domain-a.com/create](http://www.domain-a.com/create):

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain-a.com/store">
    <!-- CSRF TOKEN -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Z9SCiknYU47UEvvLWZCbZacsvOPIuPefBFh0ivkI">
    <input type="name" name="test">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[www.domain-a.com/store](http://www.domain-a.com/store):

```
// CSRF validation
// do something with post data
```

[www.domain-b.com](http://www.domain-b.com):

```
<iframe src="www.domain-a.com/create"></frame>
```

When the form stands alone in a browser window ([www.domain-a.com/create](http://www.domain-a.com/create)), the CSRF performs as expected. No CSRF token mismatch.

When the same form is implemented on domain-b.com within an iframe, after it's submitted the domain-a.com will report a mismatched CSRF token.

I tried implementing different types of HTTP headers (i.e. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain-b.com), however to no avail. Logical thing would be to turn off CSRF for the form, however I'm looking for a way to solve this without compromising CSRF.

Comment: You will need to provide more details than this; if we have no idea how your code works, we have no chance of debugging it for you.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. HTTP CORS is designed to prevent CSRF. I'm looking for a possible header that would allow CORS only for a specific domain.

Comment: I ran into the same problem on Safari. Firefox and Chrome seems fine!